# Image Slider to my iPhone application

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, xcode4, uiimage

I need this kind of component to my iPhone Application. How could I Added to this to my project.
[image]

after i click that black color I need to animated it to left side and show next one.. like that

Comment: after i click that black color I need to animated it to left side and show next one.. like that

Comment: That looks like a custom UITableViewCell. Is this what you're looking for?

Comment: What kind of component is this, pray tell?

Comment: Yeap I also guess it's better to used Table view with one cell

Answer (score 0):

Try a tableView with one row and one section. Then the action of clicking on the row can trigger the delegate method of the tableView and use that to do whatever you like.

Alternately, you can make this a button with a custom view and swap out the view each time the user taps it.

Comment: second approach is more relevant.

Comment: @Jhaliya - With the first, you get the style and animation for free, so maybe not.

Comment: didnt get about second method??

Comment: Which is the most suitable one..??

Comment: Yes agree, Could be done by both way ,i thought the second clean (less classes involved) and simple.